# How do you get the Youtube channel picture

Tags: youtube

I want to get Youtube Channel's picture. For getting Video picture it's so simple: http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + item.VideoId + "/mqdefault.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YT_CHANNEL_NAME);
        string str = "thumbnail url='";
        string ImagePic = json.Substring(json.IndexOf("thumbnail url") + str.Length);
        if (ImagePic.Contains("'"))
        {
            ImagePic = ImagePic.Remove(ImagePic.IndexOf("'"));
            ImageChannel.ImageUrl = ImagePic;

        }
```